# problem with FontSet conversion using xemacs and pstoedit in 18.04 and 16.04

Tags: fonts, emacs

Problems with font conversion ongoing with `xemacs`, sometimes with evince and after system updates around end of October 2018 in 18.04 and 16.04. `xemacs` starts with:

```
"Warning Missing charsets in String to FontSet conversion"
```

but continues to work. emacs doesn't give a warning and works fine. pstoedit which I have used for years in Ubuntu and depend on. The current ubuntu version 3.70 fails apparently with an issue locating any fonts using that `IncludeResource` command.  I tried installing all of the xfonts, that didn't work.  Adding or removing `tff-mscorefonts-installer` didn't help as some people suggested it might. 
The error I get starting with `file.ps`

```
$ pstoedit -f tgif file.ps file.obj
pstoedit: version 3.70 / DLL interface 108 (built: Aug 29 2017 - release build - g++ 7.2.0 - 64-bit) : Copyright (C) 1993 - 2014 Wolfgang Glunz
Error: /undefined in /findfont
Operand stack: ...
```

Until recently the error contained:

```
Fontconfig error: "/home/../.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", line ..
```